# Any plugin to upload file?

Tags: jquery, plugins, upload

Currently i am using

```
<input type="file">
```

Is there any other way to do this same i mean to say any plug-in or something else which can replace this tag?

Comment: @Rinkalkumar: please at least tag appropriately

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with the replacement?

Comment: To browse button which comes automatically i want to apply CSS to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.uploadify.com/, http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/ or just google for javascript/jquery upload. There are plenty of resources available.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php). The fact remains that there is no replacement for the `<input type="file">` control for loading local file contents into the browser context for `POST`ing over HTTP, but Pluploads does a fine job of providing a more intelligent interface that supports all clients OOTB.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Javascript has no access to your computer, so it can't arrange for any fileupload or anything.

You would have to either use the file input element, or use some kind of browser plugin like flash or java.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible.You have to use the type=file which notifies the broowser to select file from system interactively.